# Determine $m \in \mathbb{R}$ so that the inequality is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

What is the method to go about to solve it for:

$mx²+(m-1)x+(m-1) < 0$

Sorry if this seems too easy for the website standard, but I am working on this alone, and couldn't find a way on my own.

Comment: As a hint, you can use the quadratic formula to see where the roots will be, and then try to use this to help determine the values of $m$ that work for you (how many roots should a parabola which is always negative have...?)

Comment: Note:  if $m=1$ then $mx^2+(m-1)x+(m-1)\ge0$ for all $x\in R$

Comment: on the basis I can already set the condition of m < 0 so that the parabola always faces downwards, but I do not know if the entirety of it is negative or not.

Comment: Could you use the fact that the maximum value of $ax^2+bx+c\;$ is $\;c-\dfrac{b^2 }{4a} $?

Comment: that only ends up with a third degree polynomial division. I've made a small table for values of x and m up to 3, and your condition is correct, of m = 1, and I believe it can be said for all values over 1 as well.

Comment: I'm saying you could find $m$ such that $mx^2+(m-1)x+(m-1)\le0$ by setting $a=m, b=m-1, $ and $c=m-1$ and solving $4ac-b^2=0$

Comment: by solving the equation I end up with the fact that $4ac-b² = 0$ or $4ac-b²>0$ if $m \in [-1/3, 4/3]$. This only gives me the range where the parabola has one or two solutions. I am still lost as to how will this translate to the answer for the question itself.

Comment: don't you get $m\in[-1/3,1] $?

Comment: A typo, copied quickly from paper, I do indeed get $m \in [-1/3, 1]$ ,my question is how does that transition to the question itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find values of $m$ for which $mx^2+(m-1)x+(m-1)$ is negative for all $x\in\mathbb R$, first note that if

$m\ge0$ then $mx^2+(m-1)x+(m-1)$ takes arbitrarily large positive values, so we need $m<0$.

For $m<0$, the maximum of $mx^2+(m-1)x+(m-1)=ax^2+bx+c$ is

$c-\dfrac {b^2}{4a}=(m-1)-\dfrac{(m-1)^2}{4m}=\dfrac{(m-1)(4m-(m-1))}{4m}=\dfrac{(m-1)(3m+1)}{4m}$,

which is $0$ when $3m+1=0$, i.e., $m=-\dfrac13$; positive when $-\dfrac13<m<0$ (since then $m-1$ is negative, $4m$ is negative, and $3m+1$ is positive); and negative when $m<-\dfrac13$ (since then $m-1$, $3m+1$, and $4m$ are negative).

So the answer is that {$m\in \mathbb R|m<-\dfrac13$} is the subset of $\mathbb R$ for which $mx^2+(m-1)x+(m-1)$ takes on negative values for all $x \in \mathbb R$.